# Wht is wrong with my regex?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, oracle11g, format-string

My regex code doesnt work I am getting result like below.Any Idea

***Errors on my code:***

```
Getting the sentences without values like this one: CREATE SEQUENCE "" MINVALUE  MAXVALUE INCREMENT BY START WITH  CACHE  NOORDER NOCYCLE;
```

***Conditions for changing the sentence***

1. if MINVALUE has plus value inside the sentence than make start with value same as
   MINVALUE...
2. if MINVALUE has minus value inside the sentence than make start with value same as
   MAXVALUE

***Inside my database I have 3 sentence that needs to be change...***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 250  CACHE 50 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE "_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 151 MAXVALUE 500 INCREMENT BY 4 START WITH 160  CACHE 30 NOORDER NOCYCLE;
```

***Result should be like below***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 999 CACHE 50 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE "_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 151 MAXVALUE 500 INCREMENT BY 4 START WITH 151 CACHE 30 NOORDER NOCYCLE;
```

***My Code:***

```
            string sentence = "";
            string formatprototype = "";
            string output = "";

                using (OracleConnection conn1 = MyConnection.GetSourceConnection())
                {
                    conn1.Open();
                    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(@"MyCommand", conn1))
                    {
                        sentence = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                        string pattern = @".*[ ]+?[\""]{1}(?<String>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[\""]{1}[ ]+?MINVALUE[ ]*(?<MinValue>[-?\d]*)[ ]*MAXVALUE[ ]*(?<MaxValue>[\d]*)[ ]+?[INCREMENT]*[ ]+?[BY]*[ ]+?(?<IncrementBy>[\d]*)[ ]+?[START]*[ ]+?[WITH]*[ ]+?(?<StartWith>[\d]*)[ ]+?[CACHE]*[ ]+?(?<Cache>[\d]*)\s+?";
                        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
                        Match match = regex.Match(sentence);
                        Group @string = match.Groups[1];
                        Group minvalue = match.Groups[2];
                        Group maxvalue = match.Groups[3];
                        Group incrementby = match.Groups[4];
                        Group startswith = match.Groups[5];
                        Group cache = match.Groups[6];
                        formatprototype = @"CREATE SEQUENCE ""{0}"" MINVALUE {1} MAXVALUE {2} INCREMENT BY {3} START WITH {4} CACHE {5} NOORDER NOCYCLE";
                        if (minvalue.Value.StartsWith("-"))
                        {
                            output = string.Format(formatprototype, @string, minvalue, maxvalue, incrementby, maxvalue, cache);
                        }
                        else if (!minvalue.Value.StartsWith("-"))
                        {
                            output = string.Format(formatprototype, @string, minvalue, maxvalue, incrementby, minvalue, cache);
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show(output);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don't remove the code from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this RegEx pattern

```
(.*?MINVALUE )(-)?(?(2)(.*?MAXVALUE ))(\d+)(.*START WITH )(\d+)(.*)
```

and replace with this pattern

```
$1$2$3$4$5$4$7
```

[live Demo](http://regexr.com?3695q)

Comment: @user2760129 What do you mean? The regex that this user posted seems to work, you just need to remove some lines of code from your current code and use `Regex.Replace` instead, which significantly reduces the amount of lines you have an produce the results you wanted, at least, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for the reply.. Do I need to remove string pattern and put $1$2$3$4$5$4$7 ... I didnt understant what he was telling me actually . Can you please show me inside my code?

Comment: @user2760129 Sure. I did a quick one on [ideone](http://ideone.com/71MtlS). I'm not sure why it's displaying as html though ^^; C# is not my forte.

Comment: @Jerry I try implement inside my code but I couldn't :( Where the var regex and var result goes again? should I get rid of my   //Match match = regex.Match(sentence);

Comment: @user2760129 Sure, I'll put it on pastebin since I don't have the variables you have: [link](http://pastebin.com/3ZTB27xX).

Comment: @Jerry, I can't believe this :) It works now! Thank you very much.